# How to make 'for(){}' code simpler in R?

Tags: r

Thanks to the comment of Matthew Lundberg, here I attach a simplified example of what I want to do.

```
>id = c("A", "B")
>citations = c("P,Q", "P,Q,R,X")
>dataBase = data.frame(id, citations)
>dataBase
  id        citations
1 A         P,Q
2 B         P,Q,R,X
```

Here I want to convert 'dataBase' to 'dataNetwork' like below:

```
>dataNetwork
From    To
A       P
A       Q
B       P
B       Q
B       R
B       X
```

According to Robert Krzyzanowski who answered my question, `Reduce` seems to be useful. Is there any other useful ways you have?

---

I am new to R, and made the code to convert the csv file into the network file (From, To) for network analysis in Pajek, using 'for(){}' like below. I know there is a great way to make the code simpler in R using apply function family, but I'm not used to it. Thus, could you please help me to make this code simpler?
Thanks in advance.

```
myFile = file.choose()
myData = read.csv(myFile)
dataa = data.frame(myData$colA, myData$colB) 

id = as.vector(dataa[,1])
citationBase = strsplit(gsub(" \\|", "/", dataa[,2]), "/")

from = c(0)
to = c(0)
datab = data.frame(from, to)

m=1 #m: How many are the backward citations in the data?
for(i in 1:length(dataa[,1])){ #i: How many are the issue numbers in the data?
  citations = as.vector(citBase[[i]])
  k=1
  for(m in m:(m+length(citations)-1)){
    datab[m,1] = id[i]
    datab[m,2] = citations[k]
    k = k+1
  }
  m = m+1 
}
```

Comment: Please make this reproducible by including example data in the question.

Comment: The igraph package can export to pajek format and it may not be too difficult to get your data into an igraph structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `lapply` isn't really necessary here, since you actually are using the previous computation's result. We could use `Reduce` to keep it functional. By the way, notice that `m` *is* `i` in each iteration of the outer loop!

```
datab <- Reduce(function(df, i) {
  citations <- as.vector(citBase[[i]])
  inner_seq <- seq(m, m + length(citations)-1)
  df[inner_seq, ] <- list(rep(id[i], length(inner_seq)), citations[inner_seq - m + 1])
  df
}, seq_len(nrow(dataa)), datab)
```